# How to detect Spark application based on the executor folders?

Tags: apache-spark

I'm facing a problem of storage, while there are a lot of Spark applications are running and my Worker storage is going to full. I look for the problems in `/tmp` and found that there are some directories have a gigantic size.

Example:

```bash
57G     ./executor-3a0fb206-20f5-4bf2-a2ac-934997d8a259
2.3G    ./executor-1af8eb7a-9af5-4004-85c1-1fb692729029
2.2G    ./executor-82aeaa8a-d822-47f1-9b2c-feec8c400776
19G     ./executor-dda6c1a9-de16-4cf4-a177-23fc1d02b4e4
55G     ./executor-9712dcbd-69f6-4787-8d99-4ed4b570a79e
2.7G    ./executor-bc70b76f-effd-4d83-8feb-2bee14bd9fbe
139G    .
```

Dive into 1 directory and I got this

```
213M    ./spark-dcabdd0e-7fb8-45b6-8516-09de0f136884
31G     ./blockmgr-403d8dce-6d64-4ccd-a4f3-8579e6c82605
213M    ./spark-51589475-1436-432e-90d4-6f05a960518a
31G     ./blockmgr-7096991a-c796-47d3-ab45-19815bc3448b
```

My question is how can I identify the Spark application that owns those directories?
(I need to kill those application to prevent corruption of others application if my worker is full of storage)